# AS3 - Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3

First, I am a beginner. Second, please someone change the title as I cannot think of a better one.

This is where the problem is:

```
makebtn(0, 150, true, "btnstart");
btntxt(btnstart, "Start");
```

I made two functions, one `makebtn`: `makebtn( xpos, ypos, alignMiddle, instance name);`
number two: `btntxt`: `btntxt( target instance, displayed text);`

```
function makebtn(xpos:Number, ypos:Number, alignMiddle:Boolean, newname:String):void
{
    var button:MovieClip = new btn();
    if(alignMiddle == true){
        xpos = stage.stageWidth / 2 - button.width / 2;
    }
    button.x = xpos;
    button.y = ypos;
    button.name = newname;
    trace("Success adding button - " + button.name);
    stage.addChild(button);
    button.gotoAndStop(4);
    button.useHandCursor = false;
}

function btntxt(button:MovieClip, txt:String):void
{
    button.btnText.text = txt;
    button.buttonMode = true;
    button.useHandCursor = true;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,overListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clickListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upListener);
}
```

I made my button as a movieclip and not a simple button.

The problem displayed is Access of undefined property to `btnstart`. Is it the shortage of time causing the problem or what? Please help!

Tell me if my information is too short. I am sure the listeners are working alright.

I am creating these on **timeline**.

Well, if I put the `btntxt(button, "Start");` inside the makebtn function, that works.

## SECOND EDIT:

```
function makebtn(xpos:Number, ypos:Number, alignMiddle:Boolean, newname:String):void
{
var button:MovieClip = new btn();
if(alignMiddle == true){
    xpos = stage.stageWidth / 2 - button.width / 2;
}
button.x = xpos;
button.y = ypos;
button.name = newname;
trace("Success adding button - " + button.name);
stage.addChild(button);
button.gotoAndStop(4);
button.useHandCursor = false;
}

function btntxt(target:String, txt:String):void
{
var button;
button = getChildByName(target);
button.getChildByName("btnText").text = txt;
button.buttonMode = true;
button.useHandCursor = true;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,overListener);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outListener);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clickListener);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upListener);
}
```

Comment: You should give us the code of the functions `makebtn` and `btntxt`. More likely than not the problem is in one of these two. Also, are you coding on the timeline or in a document class?

Comment: @puggsoy please view again and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by declaring Children properly:

```
function btntxt(target:String, txt:String):void
{
    var button:MovieClip = MovieClip(stage.getChildByName(target));
    var btnText:TLFTextField = TLFTextField(button.getChildByName("btnText"));
    btnText.text = txt;
    button.buttonMode = true;
    button.useHandCursor = true;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,overListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clickListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upListener);
}
```

Comment: It's good that you've managed to resolve this issue, if with a little hint. It's what is called path to perfection :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a dynamic property by making a child and assigning it a name. It does not work this way. You might either use `getChildByName()` and invoke your function via string, like `btntxt("btnstart","Start");` or you may use a `this[]` construction to manually add a property to a dynamic MovieCkip of your main class. `this[newname]=button;`

Comment: Sorry, I changed my `btntxt` function. When I type this, it gives an error: `function btntxt(target:String, txt:String):void { var button; button = getChildByName(target); ...` How would you put getChildByName in my function?

Comment: output:TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at untitled1_fla::MainTimeline/btntxt()
 at untitled1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: it happened on: btntxt("btnstart","Start"); no compiler errors, just output messages.

Comment: 2 errors if I replace with this: `getChildByName(target).getChildByName("btnText").text = txt; getChildByName(target).buttonMode = true;` 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Ow, you need to typecast the result to `btn` type, also check if the outcome is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
var button:MovieClip;
for (var i=1; i<7; i++)
{
button = MovieClip(getChildByName("btn"+i));
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, objClick);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, objOver);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, objOut);
button.buttonMode = true;
}
```